# What is the meaning or reference of 峡天昆仑和彼岸 为谁而撼

Tags: translation, meaning

This is part of a song, but I have tried all the dictionaries and Google and can't figure what the **峡天昆仑和彼岸** is supposed to mean:

烽烟把 霜雪敲落
轻覆过 往日沉疴

你背着光 眸中有星河

我哼着歌 日月应我

没入眉心的灿烂 被尘埃熄灭又燃

**峡天昆仑和彼岸 为谁而撼**

昆仑 seems to refer to a mountain https://www.purpleculture.net/dictionary-details/?word=%E6%98%86%E4%BB%91
Still no clue about the rest of it...

Comment: I love to translate beautifully written lyrics but it is not one. The lyrics here are grammatically incoherent. Translating it would require a lot of guesswork, just like trying to understand a 3-year-old child's mumbling talk. It would be a good challenge though because one has to know the language well to provide educated and logical guesses

Comment: "峡天昆仑和彼岸 为谁而撼", the lyric writer is expressing the shocking feeling ( 震撼) felt over the difficult terrain (險峻) of the 昆仑 mountains - narrow straights between tower like mountains.

Answer (score 2):

This lyrics remind me of another lyrics, "The bear went over the mountain....what do you think he saw?...he saw another mountain...what do you think he did?...he climb the other mountain...what do you think he saw?...he saw another mountain...what do you think he did?...he climb the other mountain...what do you think he saw?...."

Thus OP's lyrics expresses this same unconquerable, fearsome majesty of nature which dwarfs all human attempts to tame it.

In order to have a better understanding OP's lyrics, one needs to have a beyond basic knowledge of ancient Chinese cultural history, the almost religious significance of its majestic geographical features in Taoist mythology.

The author, therefore, makes use of the imagery of 昆仑山, (a large mountain range stretching across North-Western China which has a historically significant position in China's cultural history, featured in many martial arts novels, 武侠小说), in the phrase, 峡天昆仑和彼岸, "The sky-high gorges of Kunlun Mountain (straddling) towards the distant shore....", as a real or imagined physical backdrop for the utter feelings of "emotional shock" when confronted with the fearsome majesty of Kunlun Mountain in the phrase, 为谁而撼, "...for whom (it) shocks, (or terrifies)"

Finally, take a look at any Chinese painting of mountains and valleys. The mountain always tower over the tiny, almost microscopic human figures which seem like an afterthought in the painter's eye.

Comment: I like this "峡天昆仑和彼岸, "The sky-high gorges of Kunlun Mountain (straddling) towards the distant shore....", ". It catches the meaning well.

Comment: Glad you like it :)

Comment: Interestingly it matches the theme of 观沧海 of 曹操, which was where the phrase 星汉灿烂(name of the song) comes from. I think.

Answer (score 1):

Let me take my guess

峡 - canyon

天 - sky

- 峡天 (canyon sky) may refer to [一線天](https://baike.baidu.hk/item/%E4%B8%80%E7%B7%9A%E5%A4%A9/1927581)

> 一線天 （山峯中常見景觀）

> 一線天，是我國名山奇峯中常有的石景，因兩壁夾峙，縫隙所見藍天如一線而得名

> One-line sky (common landscape in mountain peaks)

> A one-line sky is a common stone scene in famous mountains and strange peaks in our country.

[image]

- [昆仑](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%98%86%E4%BB%91%E5%B1%B1%E8%84%89) (Kunlun) is a famous mountain mentioned in many mythological tales

[image]

- 彼岸 is a more literary/ classical version of 对岸 meaning "the shore on the other side"
- 撼 in 为谁而撼 is short for 震撼 (shock)

> 峡天昆仑和彼岸 为谁而撼

> The canyon sky, Kunlun Mountains, and the shore on the other side, shaking up by who?

*This verse describes a shock created by someone that covered a vast area*